# Why does appending ./ to a file execute the program while just typing the program does not

Tags: bash, shell

To be more specific, what I mean is:

Suppose I have a python script called test.py with a proper shebang on the first line, say

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print 'this works'
```

In the shell, when I type:

```
$ test.py
```

Nothing happens, but when I type:

```
$ ./test.py
```

The command is invoked and prints "this works".

Why is that? I thought "." just meant the current directory. Why would having a ./ suddenly mean we want to execute whatever comes next? Thanks.

Comment: There's an environment variable called `PATH`.

Comment: `./test.py` does mean *current directory*. The problem is that `test.py` doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell only looks for executables in the path (try `echo $PATH` in the shell to see its value). If `.` is not in the path, you'll have to give the explicit path to the executable. Not having `.` in the path is a good idea: imagine somebody managed to put an executable named `ls` in your home directory!

Answer (score 1):

Because the current directory (where you had saved `test.py`) is not in your `$PATH` environment variable.

`$PATH` is searched for executables when you try to run one.